# Spring Boot - Duplicate Headers

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot

I setup a filter bean to insert cache control headers. This is working fine, except at some point after the filter, additional cache control headers are being inserted.

I am using Spring Boot.

Any ideas on what could be causing the issue?

```
public class CacheControlFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Calendar expires = Calendar.getInstance();
        expires.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);

        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

        // Returns false
        System.out.println("==========> " + httpResponse.containsHeader("Cache-Control"));

        httpResponse.addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=" + (expires.getTimeInMillis() / 1000));
        httpResponse.addDateHeader("Expires", expires.getTimeInMillis());

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

See the duplicate cache control headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Cache-Control: max-age=1411755690
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: Fri, 26 Sep 2014 18:21:30 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: image/png
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out Spring Security adds them by default when using Java configuration.  Here is how they can be disabled:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      // ...
        .headers().disable();
   }
}
```

Comment: Instead of disabling all of Spring Security's headers, you may wish to narrow them down so that you still get the other headers while plugging in your own cache control ones. Read http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.5/reference/htmlsingle/#default-security-headers for more details.

Comment: Link to spring docs does not work anymore. I guess this one is now the good one: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#default-security-headers

Comment: This solution disables all the headers from Spring Security.

Answer (score 1):

Use `setHeader` instead of `addHeader`.

[Spring Security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#headers-cache-control) says:

> If you actually want to cache specific responses, your application can
>   selectively invoke `HttpServletResponse.setHeader(String,String)` to
>   override the header set by Spring Security. This is useful to ensure
>   things like CSS, JavaScript, and images are properly cached.

Or you can specify the URLs that need different cache control using:

```
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
            .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
            .setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    // ...
}
```